# htaccess rewrite add trailing slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following url :

```
http://localhost/PROJECTNAME?gallery_detail.php?id=1
```

Which i am rewriting to this : http://localhost/PROJECTNAME/username/id

I have used following code for that:

```
RewriteRule /(\w+)$ gallery_detail.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule /$ gallery_detail.php?id=$1 [L]
```

And it's working fine but when i am removing the id and slash it redirects me to the 404 page. how can i forcefully add trail slash at the end of the url or is there any other way to do that.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using a leading slash in RewriteRule's pattern (See your first rule) . htaccess doesnot accept  leading slash in its pattern,you need to remove this. You can use the following rule with an optional trailing slash :

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /gallery_detail.php?id=$1 [L]
```